# Backbone.js model property constants - is this good practice?

Tags: backbone.js

I have trouble keeping track of the properties of a Model instance.  For example I have declarations such as:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Then in my views, I'm often doing something like:

```
var someVal = this.model.get('someProperty');
```

I was beginning the task of moving a View's strings into constants by encapsulating them in an object and passing it as a second parameter to a View's constructor, for example:

```
SchemaOptionsView = Backbone.View.extend(
    { /* Body of View here as usual */}, 
    {
        TEMPLATE: '#View-Template',
        INPUT_REQUIRED:'required'
    });
```

When  I got to thinking, I could solve two problems by doing this with my Models:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend(
{ /* Body of Model here as usual */},
{
    PROPERTY_1 = 'p1',
    PROPERTY_2 = 'p2'
});
```

I could then use the constant to retrieve the property value:

```
var someVal = this.model.get(MyModel.PROPERTY_1);
```

This would allow me to clearly see the properties a Model instance contains, and also moves a string value into a constant in an appropriate place.

I have not seen this recommended or in any examples. Have I missed something? What do people think about this idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solving a non problem. Your models should have well defined attributes - we use the defaults hash to enumerate all the available attributes of our models. Not only does this provide a catalog of the attributes that a model possesses but it also provides a way to override a non-validated input.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you enumerate a Model's available properties?

Comment: @Jack Yes.  The defaults hash for the model declaration. If you look at the examples on my [validation library](http://github.com/toddself/Backbone.Validator/) you'll see exactly what I'm referencing.

Comment: @Jack I know this is a quite oldpost but might help someone in the wild. 
So, you'd do for model myModel 
myModel.toJSON() returns an objectcontaining all its properties