# Backbone.js - Using new() in Model defaults - circular reference

Tags: backbone.js

Taking the following Model:

```
MyModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    myNestedModel:undefined,
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.set({myNestedModel: new MyNestedModel());
  }
});
```

It has a single property named 'myNestedModel' which has the following definition:

```
MyNestedModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    myModel:undefined,
  }
});
```

It too has a single Property name 'myModel'. Now if I create an instance of MyModel:

aModel = new MyModel();

The nested model will have been set in MyModel's initialize method. I then use JSON.stringify in a two step process:

```
// Use Backbone.js framework to get an object that we can use JSON.stringfy on
var modelAsJson = aModel.toJSON();

// Now actually do stringify 
var modelAsJsonString = JSON.stringify(modelAsJson);
```

This works fine and I get the JSON representation of MyModel and it's property of MyNestedModel.  The problem occurs when I use defaults, for example:

```
MyModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults : {
        new MyNestedModel(),
      }
    });
```

This causes a problem with JSON.stringify since it doesn't support circular references. I assume the circular reference is being created because all instances of MyModel share the same instance of MyNestedModel. Whereas the initialize method creates a new nested model for each instance.

### **Questions:**

1. Is my understanding of `defaults:{}` being the 'cause' of the
   problem correct?
2. [From a question I posted recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040128/backbone-js-model-property-constants-is-this-good-practice/10050603#10050603) I got the
       impression I should be using defaults for all properties. If that is
       the case, how should I be using defaults in the scenario presented
       in this post/question?
3. Can someone clarify the use of `defaults:{}`
       with regards to when the value applies, when it's overridden and
       whether instances share the same default 'instances'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defaults is used only for attributes inside your model ( the data in the model ), and whenever you create your model it takes the values from defaults and sets the attributes. e.g.

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults : {
         rating : 0
     }
})

User1 = new User({ name : 'jack', email : 'jack@gmail.com' });
User2 = new User({ name : 'john', email : 'john@gmail.com' });

User1.set({ rating : 2 });
```

Now your two models when called with toJSON will print

```
{
   rating: 2,
   name: 'jack',
   email: 'jack@gmail.com'
}
{
   rating: 0,
   name: 'john',
   email: 'john@gmail.com'
}
```

Since defaults is an object, every value you place there is evaluated immediately so :

```
defaults : {
    rating : defaultRating()
}
```

will call defaultRating() - not everytime when you initialize the model, but immediately ( in the extend method )

You should use defaults for models where you need some data to exist on the creating of the model ( e.g. new myModel() )

In your example you have the following mistakes :

1.set a value without a property

```
 defaults : {
      PROPERTY : new Model() 
 }
```

2.you don't need such an option for your defaults - you should place there only attributes ( data ) for the model

Defaults applies always as long as it is not replaced by a new defaults in an extended model e.g.

```
 var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ defaults : { alpha : 'beta' } });
 var myModel = Model.extend({ defaults : { beta : 'gama' } });
```

now your myModel when initialized will have

```
 { beta : 'gama' } // alpha : 'beta' will not be set as value, because it is replaced
```

Comment: Excellent!  This is completely non-intuitive.  I was doing `"subItems: []"` and even that messed up.  Thanks for this. +1