# Can't set default attribute due to circular reference with Backbone-relational

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm using Backbone with Backbone-relational. I have two models, `Appointment` and `Client`, where a `Client` can have many `Appointments`. Here's my `Client` model definition (in CoffeeScript):

```
class Snip.Models.Client extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  paramRoot: 'client'

  relations: [
    type: Backbone.HasMany
    key: 'appointments'
    relatedModel: 'Snip.Models.Appointment'
    collectionType: 'Snip.Collections.AppointmentsCollection'
    reverseRelation:
      type: Backbone.HasOne
      key: 'client'
      includeInJSON: 'id'
  ]

  defaults:
    name: null
    phone: null
    email: null
    notes: null
    active: null

class Snip.Collections.ClientsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Snip.Models.Client
  url: '/clients'
```

And here's my `Appointment` model definition:

```
class Snip.Models.Appointment extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  paramRoot: 'appointment'

  defaults:
    time_block_type_code: 'APPOINTMENT'
    start_time: null
    stylist: null
    salon: null
    client: Snip.Models.Client() # This doens't work

class Snip.Collections.AppointmentsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Snip.Models.Appointment
  url: '/appointments'
```

Here's the problem: since `Client` references `Appointment`, I need to include the `Appointment` file before the `Client` file so the `Snip.Models.Appointment` class will exist by the time I reference it. However, `Appointment` *also* references `Client`, so it's kind of a catch-22 situation. I don't know what to do.

Comment: According to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060561/backbone-js-using-new-in-model-defaults-circular-reference), maybe I'm not supposed to do `client: Snip.Models.Client()`. If I don't do it there, though, where do I do it? The `client` attribute needs to be a `Snip.Models.Client`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when using Backbone-Relational don't forget to [initialize](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/#known-problems-and-solutions) reverse relations:

```
Snip.Models.Client.setup()
```

Second, in your defaults in key `client` should be attrs for new client model (It will be created by Backbone-Relational). And if you don't have any leave empty hash:

```
client: {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying that if I call `setup()`, I can expect Backbone-relational to pick up that `client: {}` under `defaults` and automatically generate a new `Client` object?

Comment: It didn't work for me at first for some reason, but now it does. Awesome. Thanks again.